# Animated text in video using Android Transition framework

Tags: android, animation, ffmpeg, frameworks, transition

Is it possible to add user-customized animated text to a video using [Android Transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) framework? My team currently has access to a library that can animate text, but it only works with Android View objects. Therefore, the library cannot be applied to video.

They are contemplating using FFMPEG port for rendering text animations to the video, but I would like to know if there is a simpler way.

There are a few commercial SDKs like magisto, but they seem to be too basic for what we are doing.

If this can be done using [Android Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html), what are your recommendations?

Comment: Android Transition framework? [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) one?

Comment: Yes, that one is what I was referring to.

Comment: so what kind of animations do you want to get (different from standard [property animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html))?

Comment: @user446718 did you find any way to use Transitions on Video? I am trying to implement it but cant find anything,